# Promotion Activity Done by some user

Tags: discussion, support

Today in tag Edit I notice that below user

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/71160/shahzad

add some promotional links in tag edits, So I rejected those Edits (Example below)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/134743

I am requesting same to other users please read edit suggestion and then accept or reject edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reporting. We have contacted the user

Comment: please check this post as well https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164852/magento-2-accepting-payment-in-saudi-riyal-for-paypal